# Как в С# извлечь элемент HashSet по индеку?

Tags: c#, hashset

Есть HashSet

```
HashSet<int> nxn = new HashSet<int>();
Random rnd = new Random();
while ( nxn.Count != 9 )
{
   nxn.Add(rnd.Next(ot, to));
}
```

Нужно занести его в целочисленный массив. Пытался сделать через .CopyTo(), но он, насколько я понял, работает только с одномерными массивами. Как в HashSet извлекать элементы по индексу?

Comment: `CopyTo`, кстати, тоже должно было работать

Answer (score 2):

**UPD:** судя по всему вопрос в теле отличается от вопроса в заголовке.

Для того, чтобы получить массив из [`HashSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) достаточно воспользоваться методом расширения [`ToArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb298736(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var arr = hashSet.ToArray();
```

---

[`HashSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) реализует интерфейс [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx), для классов реализующих этот интерфейс есть метод расширения [`ElementAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb299233(v=vs.110).aspx)

Поэтому формально ответ на вопрос будет:

```
hashSet.ElementAt(index);
```

При этом каждый раз будет пройдена вся коллекция с первого элемента, до элемента с индексом `index`

Как подсказывает [@Андрей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/720257/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%A1-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-hashset-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83/720277?noredirect=1#comment1084555_720277)

> Следует добавить, что `HashSet` **не гарантирует** порядок возврата, поэтому `ElementAt(x)` может возвращать разные элементы, например, до и после очередного добавления в `HashSet`

---

Если нужен доступ по случайному индексу - то стоит использовать другую коллекцию.

Comment: Следует добавить, что HashSet не гарантирует порядок возврата, поэтому `ElementAt(x)` может возвращать разные элементы, например, до и после очередного добавления в HashSet

Comment: @Андрей, Добавил